# Not able to create Custom NER Project from existing tagged JSON file

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to implement a custom named entity recognition project; I already created a storage container an uploaded data that are already tagged, when creating a new project I can select the storage container and tagged file,

[image]

but when I click on "Create Project" it is showing an error like below

[image]

`Both intents and entities in project JSON can't be null or empty. If you want to create an empty project, please use the create project API instead.`

But the point is, in the json document every object has "entities" defined, none of the entities are null or empty!

Is this a technical issue from Azure, or can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is some changes for the excepted format, I will reach out to product team to check.

For now, please try my sample format, this works to me, I only labeled date in my sample.

{"intentNames":[],"entityNames":["date"],"entityHierarchySeparator":null,"documents":[{"text":null,"location":"01.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":9,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":9,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"02.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":10,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":10,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"03.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":9,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":9,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"04.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":9,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":9,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"05.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":9,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":9,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"06.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":8,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":8,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"07.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":9,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":9,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"08.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":10,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":10,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"09.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":10,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":10,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null},{"text":null,"location":"10.txt","culture":"en-us","intents":null,"entities":[{"regionStart":5,"regionLength":9,"labels":[{"entity":0,"start":5,"length":9,"autoTagged":false}]}],"datasets":null}]}